# Why this code iterates twice against my will, and why i get null?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Kos Aima Shel Kolhem, Kolam aim toar be CS Aval afhad lo yodel lama ze mahzir null. Tamoto.

Im trying to build a chat app. I have no problem sending the message to the firebase, but when i try to read it, it crashes saying that the I am getting null.

When i printed the information and tried to get only the part that it says is null, it printed it twice as if I'm iterating over it.

In the first iteration i get a id of the receiver (in this case, because that's what i asked for), and in the second iteration I'm getting null and I don't know why. I am trying to get the receiver (should return it's id, in the first iteration i get the id as expected, and in the second I'm getting null).

I want the `dataSnapshot` to return the receiver id, and create an `instance` of `class Chat` from the information in the `dataSnapshot`. The value of the returned data snap shot is:
the message i sent, the receiver of this message, and the sender (current user).

my code:

```
private void readMessages(final String myId, final String userId) {
    chatList = new ArrayList<>();
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(CHATS);
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Chat chat = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + chat.getReceiver());
            **if (chat.getReceiver().equals(userId)) { ** > crashing here, saying getReceiver is null
                chatList.add(chat);
            }
            adapter = new ConversationAdapter(chatList);
            converstaionRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

my Chat class:

```
public class Chat {

    String sender;
    String receiver;
    String message;

    public Chat(String sender, String receiver, String message) {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Chat() {
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(String sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public String getReceiver() {
        return receiver;
    }

    public void setReceiver(String receiver) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

the json at CHATS:

```
{
    "chats" :
    {
        "-M-l8qvu9AXe9sCSKoKf" :
        {
            "message" : "h\n",
            "receiver" : "receiver id (to whom i sent)",
            "sender" : "current user id "
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See What log „onDataChanged:” shows you.

Comment: first it returns the id of the receiver as i wanted, but in the second iteration it returns a null. i will edit the post if you want. i don't know why it iterating twice. and why i get null.

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: i am using java and he is kotltin. but i will try, just one thing, if i send a message, will it appear in realtime to the other side ? like WhatsApp and other things?